# Process getRuntime doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, linux, windows, jboss, openshift

In my PC (Windows) my JSP file runs correctly:

- inputFile.1x2 (C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\PFC\P151x2\Apostes)
- apostes1x2.class (C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\PFC\P151x2\Apostes)
- outputFile.tmp (C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\PFC\P151x2\Apostes)

  ```
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c java apostes1x2 PFC/P151x2/Apostes/inputFile.1x2 > PFC/P151x2/Apostes/outputFile.tmp");
  while (process.waitFor()!=0){}
  ```

my JSP file creates a TMP file (with content).

Otherwise, in Ubuntu:

- inputFile.1x2 (/opt/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/PFC/P151x2/Apostes)
- apostes1x2.class (/opt/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/PFC/P151x2/Apostes)
- outputFile.tmp (/opt/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/PFC/P151x2)

  ```
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java apostes1x2 PFC/P151x2/Apostes/inputFile.1x2 > PFC/P151x2/Apostes/outputFile.tmp");
  while (process.waitFor()!=0){}
  ```

my JSP file creates a TMP file (without content).

**My questions (3):**

1. It's possible that my cloud (at OpenShift) works as a Windows Server and not as a Linux server?
2. Somebody can see the correct process in Ubuntu? If I make in commands:

   cd /opt/jboss-6.1.0.Final/bin/PFC/P151x2/Apostes
   java apostes1x2 inputFile.1x2

I can see the content again. So, my CLASS file runs OK.

3. It exists another clouds with Java and JBoss AS (Windows server)?

Comment: My post contains 3 questions. I need to know if OpenShift offers JBoss AS in Windows server, what is my correct process in Ubuntu (Linux), according to my JSP file and files, and to know alternative webs to OpenShift with JBoss AS (and Java) in Windows server.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for basic information on asking questions on StackOverflow.  Hint: ONE question per post.

Comment: OpenShift Online runs on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) hosted on Amazon, but you must understand how to work, Openshift is [PaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) cloud service. About supported technologies take a look in https://www.openshift.com/products/technologies

Comment: You dont loop on process.waitFor(). it waits till the program ends and returns the status. When you loop the situation does not change.